# How to drag and drop element in Angular application with cypress?

Tags: angular, cypress

I would like to drag and drop element from a list to reorder it using a move icon .

So, I've added 3 items and I've tried this function :
array-form.po.ts :

```
export const dragdropItem = (dragedElSelector) => {
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
if(dragedElSelector == null){
  console.log(dragedElSelector)
}
cy.get(dragedElSelector).then(($form) => {
  const coordsDrag = $form[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  cy.wrap($form)
    .trigger('dragstart', {
      clientX: coordsDrag.left,
      clientY: coordsDrag.top,
      which: 1,
      dataTransfer
    })
    .trigger('mousemove', {
      dataTransfer
    });
  cy.get(dragedElSelector).trigger('drop', {
    dataTransfer
  });
});
```

};

array-form.spec.ts :

```
it('should add item and reorder the list of arrayForm with dragdrop', () => {
  getAddItemButton().click();
  getArrayFormRows().should('have.length', 3);
  getCollapsedButton().eq(2).click();
  getArrayFormTextFieldThird().type('3');
  getPassengerComboBox().should('be.visible');
  getPassengerComboBoxThird().click({force:true});
  getPassengerComboBoxValueThird().click({force:true});
  getPassengerComboBoxThird().should('contain', 'Gauss Capital');
  getPassengerComboBoxThird().click({force:true});
  cy.wait(2000);
  dragdropItem(
    getMoveIcon().eq(0)
  );
  cy.wait(1000);             
});
```

But I got this error :

`$form[0].getBoundingClientRect is not a function`

can anyone help me please .

Comment: Your images do not work so we can’t see the error. Maybe add them as text?

Comment: This is the error : $form[0].getBoundingClientRect is not a function